# Can the coefficients used to prove a set of functions is linearly dependent be imaginary?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Example: $\cos x$, $e^{ix}$, $3\sin x$.

I can show: $C_1\cos x + C_2 e^{ix} + C_33\sin x = 0$ if $(C_1,C_2,C_3) = (1,-1,i/3)$

But i don't know if $C_3 = i/3$ is a valid coefficient to choose.  Can such coefficients be imaginary?

Comment: If you read the particular exercise, it is most probably written there that the vector space in question is over $\Bbb R$ or over $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Linear dependency also depends on the field

For example take $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$ then we can prove that $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$
are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but clearly they are
not linearly independent in $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$

The underlying field should be mentioned in the question asked